cernlib in ubuntu 24.04 LTS Noble Numbat
In Ubuntu 22 I've installed the cernlib how suggested in an answer to the post "No cernlib on Ubuntu 22.04", namely adding in /etc/apt/sources.list (now /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources) the focal repository. But now I've installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Noble Numbat and adding the focal repository in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.source as
Types: deb
URIs: http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: focal focal-updates focal-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
Then when I try the command "sudo apt install cernlib", it answers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cernlib
Do you know how to solve this problem?
Thanks. Michele

Please edit your question and specify what "does not work" mean - do you get any error messages? If yes, please add them to your question.

I've edited my question, I hope that now to have bettere clarified my problem

Check if cernlib is available in the Focal repository: You added the focal repository, but it may not work with Ubuntu 24.04. You can try searching for the package:
sudo apt update
sudo apt search cernlib

If it doesn’t show up, it means cernlib is not available for Ubuntu 24.04.
Option 2: Add the repositories from Ubuntu 20.04 focal. Add the following:
 deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg]      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
 deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg] http://  archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
 deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
 deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

Install from source: If the package is unavailable, you can try installing cernlib manually by downloading and compiling it.
Install necessary tools by running these commands:

 sudo apt install build-essential gfortran gcc make libx11-dev libncurses-dev

Download the source code:
 wget https://cernlib.web.cern.ch/cernlib/download/cernlib-2006.tar.gz

Extract and install:
     tar -xzvf cernlib-2006.tar.gz
     cd cernlib-2006

Follow the instructions in the extracted folder to compile and install cernlib.

You can also use a docker container with cernlib already installed.
I hope this helps you.
